# API node service and MongoDB service

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We currently have an API service that simply fulfills requests for data in a mongoDB database hosted in Atlas.  We have a separate node service that the API service calls to actually get/put data in the mongoDB database.  I'm wondering if the API service should not just access the mongoDB database directly.  It seems simpler, less services to maintain, scale, potential issues with to simply have the API service access the mongoDB database directly.  I'd appreciate anyone's thoughts on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your API service is secure, I see no need for the node service step. I have an API that has read/write access to my MongoDB Atlas instance and it works just fine. I also use monitoring such as New Relic and I'd hate to have to include another service in that for no reason. I'd say, if you can track the latency etc of queries with the node service and without, you will probably benefit from removing that step.